# ASP.NET MVC - Filter By Date Range

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a date field "*Fecha*". I need filter my table using date range and this field.

This is my Controller:

```
// GET: tb_visitas
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? startdate, DateTime? enddate)
{
    var tb_visitas = db.tb_visitas.Include(t => t.tb_brochuras).Include(t => t.tb_despertai).Include(t => t.tb_estrangeiros).Include(t => t.tb_folhetos).Include(t => t.tb_livros).Include(t => t.tb_sentinela);
    return View(tb_visitas.ToList());   
}
```

This is my Model **public partial class tb_visitas**:

```
public int id_visita { get; set; }
[Required]
public int id { get; set; }
[Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> id_g { get; set; }
public string videos { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> id_fol { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> id_livros { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> id_broc { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> id_wp { get; set; }
public string Relatorio { get; set; }

public virtual tb_brochuras tb_brochuras { get; set; }
public virtual tb_despertai tb_despertai { get; set; }
public virtual tb_estrangeiros tb_estrangeiros { get; set; }
public virtual tb_folhetos tb_folhetos { get; set; }
public virtual tb_livros tb_livros { get; set; }
public virtual tb_sentinela tb_sentinela { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sorry! How can i filter my table by date range? Exemple: filter the records between 01/03/2018 and 09/03/2018.

Comment: Why can't you do a Where operation on the collection?

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ's .Where() method.

```
// GET: tb_visitas
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? startdate, DateTime? enddate)
{
    var tb_visitas = db.tb_visitas.Include(t => t.tb_brochuras)
      .Include(t => t.tb_despertai)
      .Include(t => t.tb_estrangeiros)
      .Include(t => t.tb_folhetos)
      .Include(t => t.tb_livros)
      .Include(t => t.tb_sentinela)
      .Where(t => t.Fecha >= startdate && t.Fecha <= enddate);
    return View(tb_visitas.ToList());   
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/using-linq

Comment: Works! Thanks! How can i OrderBy "Fecha" using this exemple?